# css animation: transform origin not appearing to work correctly

Tags: css, animation

I am working on this 3 panel card opening animation.. Here is an example of what I have so far.. [example](http://codepen.io/justcald/pen/ZOYZxQ?editors=1111). This is the class that I'm applying for the second animation and transform-origin just doesn't seem to do what I think it should.. But I'm pretty new at this animation stuff.

```
.two-right {
  transform: rotateY(170deg);
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
}
```

As you can see the problem is that I cant get the second animation to open correctly.. On the left side it works just fine but on the right the card isn't opening correctly on the right side of the card.. Right now I'm just poking around and haven't been able to find anything. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found the answer to my own question.. The reason is that the flip is based on it's parent.. That's why it is rotating on the wrong axis but after it's scaled and the animation is complete it ends up being positions in the correct location.

Instead of trying to do the animations I put a timeout in the javascript to let it scale and then add the flip animation later. Here is the completed code.

[Complete example](http://codepen.io/justcald/pen/EyaBxG?editors=0110)

```
.two-right {
/*   transform: rotateY(170deg); */
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
}
.two-flip {
  transform: rotateY(160deg);
}
```

I first add the .two-right class and then the .two-flip half a second later.